# A PSReadline hotkey to not enter a command to the previous command history?

Tags: powershell

This is something I am constantly finding myself in need of.

For example, I have a "macro" that I defined via **Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler**:

```
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord F3 -ScriptBlock {
  [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::RevertLine()            #clear the current buffer first
  [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::Insert('Clear-Host')    #Insert Clear-Host
  [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::AcceptLine()            #Execute buffer
}
```

Its essentially a very fast way to clear the terminal. The problem that arises is that, if I press `Up` arrow, `Clear-Host` will be what gets pulled up, which is what the `F3` macro enters.

I need something like `[Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::DontInsertIntoHistory()` so that I can exclude `Clear-host` from getting logged into history.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `Clear-Host` *directly*, which keeps it out of the command history:

```bash
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord F3 -ScriptBlock {
  Clear-Host
  [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::Insert('')
}
```

Note:

- `[Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::Insert('')` is needed to make the *prompt string* reappear.
- Curiously, this doesn't work if you press <kbd>F3</kbd> while the cursor is on the terminal window's *first* line - but if you're on the first line, there's no good reason to clear the screen anyway.

Comment: It never occured to me I could just call `Clear-Host` inside the block! I really want to start thinking outside the box like you. It works even better than I expected. For example if I trigger the hotkey while the buffer has 'get-childitem -path...', it will erase all previous command output, leaving the buffer. Awesome! Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @gaberiel__; my pleasure. Nice that it preserves the current command line being edited after clearing the screen - I hadn't even noticed that.